# Adding OpenLDAP support to PHP after compilation

Tags: php, openldap, compiled

So i'm currently migrating from php5 to php7, the problem is that the new php7 version (entreprise version) wasn't compiled using the **--with-ldap[=DIR]** option. Unfortunetly, i can only use this version.

Does anyone know if you can add the path to the LDAP directory to the PHP configuration after the compilation ?

I'd like to add that i am using PHP through Apache (if it's any help)

Comment: What operating system are you using? Can you use [Ondrej's repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) to install appropriate PHP with corresponding extensions? You can only recompile PHP with the mentioned flag if you require LDAP support.

Comment: The main problem is that i have to use my company's version of PHP (for security reasons), that's why i'm trying to find a way to add it after, but if i understand it's not possible ?

Comment: I'm on RHEL7 btw